# 80's/90's show transformation using gem/ruby

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I saw the show when I was very young, maybe about 17-19 years ago (around the year 2000). I hope someone can remember the show's name. It goes something like this. There was this guy walking in the desert when he saw a mummy which was trying to steal a red ruby from him. The ruby is some kind of transformation stone which has to be tossed up into the air to transform and therefore the mummy transform using the stone. I don't really know much about the details. Any clues?

Comment: Live action? Cartoon? Did the mummy get the stone and transform or did it just want to transform?

Comment: Vaguely feels like you caught a Mum-Ra (sp?) bit out of Thundercats.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like the cartoon [Mummies Alive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mummies_Alive!).

[image]

Here is the transformation sequence:

Comment: It is helpful if you provide some form of transcript or description for any linked videos or images.  The images are simple enough:  the text of the link becomes an alt= text.  The videos require a bit of journalistic work on your part.  Sometimes the video vanishes, or viewability is very vexing with some web-browsers (like mine).